# Multiple Parameters in Crystal Report with delimeter

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am new to Crystal reports. I have a report that uses multiple parameters. In my report, how can i use the multiple parameter with comma as delimeter? Right now, I have set the Allow multiple values =True. It works fine if there is no delimeter.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Assuming delimeter you want to use is `,`

```
join(parameter,",");
```